# What does "end of a day" mean  for Google Analytics session lifetime?

Tags: google-analytics

According to:
http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/08/update-to-sessions-in-google-analytics.html
the GA session cookie (__utmb cookie) expires when more than 30 minutes passed without any user input, traffic source changed *OR* at the end of a day. 
What does this last condition mean, is it 24h max lifetime since the visit started, is a hard limit set to midnight (if yes, what timezone?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "end of day" is midnight according to the settings of the Google Analytics profile.

So, there's a single universal "midnight" for each profile; it doesn't vary by the location or time for the local user.

If you didn't manually alter it to your preferred time zone, the default value is set to GMT -0700 US Pacific.

You can manually change the time zone in your Profile Settings:

[image]

Note that changing your time zone is a disruptive activity, since your GA data will be affected for the number of hours you change.

If you change forward in time, you'll end up with "empty" hours on the day of the transition.

If you change back in time, you'll end up with double-filled hours on the day of the transition.